# HTC one e8 Stuck at htc logo

Tags: rom, bootloader, system-error, htc-one

it wil only startup after a factory restart but after a second it says com.android.settings stopped. after that i cant reach any app because of the black background after a minute it turns itself into the HTC one logo screen. i tried several ROM updates they all didnt work it gave error 155.

Answer (score 0):

did you try flashing a suitable RUU? Boot your phone in Fastboot mode then flah the RUU file.

[*For mods: there is no way to put a comments in the Android app. I can only comment on my own answer.- Please move this comment*]

Comment: Same error. maybe the wrong ruu update? This one is for my phone http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-one-e8-sprint/news/

Comment: <T215257><DEBUG><CMD>htc_fastboot devices</CMD>
</DEBUG></T215257>
<T215258><DEBUG><OUT>FA49BSP02662 fastboothtc_fastboot finished. total time: 0.193s</OUT>
</DEBUG></T215258>
<T215258><DEBUG><CMD>htc_fastboot -s FA49BSP02662 getvar boot-mode</CMD>
</DEBUG></T215258>

Comment: the last 6 sentences  of the last log of the ruu update^

Comment: Hummm;;; I see no error from the log. Does the flashing process succeed? what happens when you run the RUU? May be an hardware issue, probably the eMMC got corrupted or something